# Angular 4 - Observable catch error

Tags: angular

How can I solve the problem of return with error, use the capture inside the Observable?

I want to execute a function inside the catch, to do some validation before the subscribe is executed.

Thank you in advance, thank you very much for your attention.

Error occurs  in -> .catch( (e) => {console.log(e)} )

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

import { MEAT_API } from '../app.api';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class  CompareNfeService {


    constructor(private http: AuthHttp) { }

    envirArquivos(order): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        return this.http.post(`${MEAT_API}compare/arquivo`, order,
        new ResponseOptions({headers: headers}))
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch( (e) => {console.log(e)} );
    }
}
```

Error

> ERROR in /XXXXXX/application/src/app/compare/service.ts (28,17):
>   Argument of type '(e: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '(err: any, caught: Observable) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
>   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to use the `catch()` of the `Observable` you need to use `Observable.throw()` method before delegating the error response to a method

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

import { MEAT_API } from '../app.api';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class CompareNfeService {


  constructor(private http: AuthHttp) {}

  envirArquivos(order): Observable < any > {
    const headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.post(`${MEAT_API}compare/arquivo`, order,
        new ResponseOptions({
          headers: headers
        }))
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch((e: any) => Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(e)));
  }

  errorHandler(error: any): void {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Using `Observable.throw()` worked for me

Answer (score 24):

With angular 6 and rxjs 6 `Observable.throw()`, `Observable.off()` has been deprecated instead you need to use `throwError`

ex :

```
return this.http.get('yoururl')
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.json()),
    catchError((e: any) =>{
      //do your processing here
      return throwError(e);
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 16):

catch needs to return an observable.

```
.catch(e => { console.log(e); return Observable.of(e); })
```

if you'd like to stop the pipeline after a caught error, then do this:

```
.catch(e => { console.log(e); return Observable.of(null); }).filter(e => !!e)
```

this catch transforms the error into a null val and then filter doesn't let falsey values through.  This will however, stop the pipeline for ANY falsey value, so if you think those might come through and you want them to, you'll need to be more explicit / creative.

edit:

better way of stopping the pipeline is to do

```
.catch(e => Observable.empty())
```

Comment: Or just `.catch(e => Observable.never())`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using below

```
return Observable.throw(error || 'Internal Server error');
```

Import the `throw` operator using the below line

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: only if you want to pass the error through. If your goal is to truly handle / catch the error, then you shouldn't rethrow.

Comment: @bryan60 elaborate please!

Comment: Observable.throw() throws an error, so that the rest of the observable sequence skips and you go straight to the error handler of the subscriber.  You can optionally not rethrow and just return an observable if this is not your intended behavior. It really depends on your use case.