# Angular how to print out server response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how can I get the error response from the server? If I only print out the error message, Http failure response for ... 400 appears. 
When I look in the Network tab of my browser I can see the error message:
"{"error": "Username already taken"}

How can I print out the real Response?
Here is my Code:

```
const req = this.http.post('URL', {
    .....
  })
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
);
```

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610218/angular-handle-for-500-server-errors/52610490#52610490 --> how to use interceptor to react to specific error codes in your Angular app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.http.post('URL', {})
.subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  error => {
       console.log(error);
      }
);
```

Comment: @PeterMüller  Let me help you. What exactly do you want to get ?

Comment: You can use developer tools to debug your code and check the objects

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.getReplyConfigs = {
        url: $rootScope.ROUTES.twitter.ViewMessageReplyInStatus,
        method: 'POST',
        data: () => ({
            pk_statusid: null
        }),
        excel: true,
        heightInModal: '500px',
        rowcount: 20,
        project: true,
        tag: true,
        OnSuccess: (response) => {
            //  $scope.getReplyModel = [...[{ new: "new" }] , ...response.data];
            $scope.loadingForLike = false;
        }`

Answer (score -1):

If you directly want to show response then try this

```
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

but this is not good practice.