# Navigate to the specific page after implementing role base authorisation in my Angular 6

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular6

I have created a frontend using Angular 6 and I want role based authorisation and have implemented using JWT helper-service. Unfortunately I can't navigate to the specific page after successfully authorising, I have tried several ways but I can't get the right solution please help me. I am a newbie in angular everything seems to work fine but on navigating to the specific page is where the problem come along.

*login.componet.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth: AuthService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  loginUser(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault()
    const target = event.target
    const email= target.querySelector('#email').value
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value

     this.Auth.getUserDetails(email,password).subscribe(data =>{
       if(this.Auth.isAuthenticated(),data.token)
       {
        localStorage.setItem('token',data.token);

         return true;
       }

       else
       {
         window.alert(data.message);
       }
     });
     console.log(email,password)
  }

}
```

*role.guard.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( public auth: AuthService,public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    // this will be passed from the route config
    // on the data property
    const admintype = route.data.admintype;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // decode the token to get its payload
    const tokenPayload = decode(token);
    if (
      !this.auth.isAuthenticated() || 
      tokenPayload.role !== admintype
    ) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }    
    return true;
  }

}
```

*auth.guard.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService,private router:Router, private user: UserService)
  {

  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }

        return true    
    }

}
```

*Auth.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
interface myData
{
  success:boolean,
  message: string,
  token:"token"

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  uri : String = 'http://localhost:4000';

  private jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // Check whether the token is expired and return
    // true or false

    if(token==null)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else{
       return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)

    }
  }


  getUserDetails(email: String,password:String){

    //post these details to the database
    return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/auth`,{ email,password});
  }

    signupadminsections(email:String,password:String,name:String,admintype:String,college:String,department:String)
  {
    //add new admin section
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/register`,{ email,password,name,admintype,college,department});
  }

}
```

*app.module.ts*

````
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatTableModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material'
import { RoleGuard } from './role.guard'

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AdmindashboardComponent } from './components/admindashboard/admindashboard.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { ViewallstudentsComponent } from './components/viewallstudents/viewallstudents.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { AddsectionadminsComponent } from './components/addsectionadmins/addsectionadmins.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './components/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { JwtHelperService, JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AdmindashboardComponent,
    ViewallstudentsComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    AddsectionadminsComponent,
    PagenotfoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    JwtModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent

      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component:AdminComponent,
        data:{
          admintype:['admin']
         },
        canActivate :[RoleGuard],
      },
      {
       path:'addsectionadmin',
       component:AddsectionadminsComponent,
       data:{
        admintype:['admin']
       },
       canActivate:[AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'admindashboard',
        component: AdmindashboardComponent,
        data:{
          admintype:['sectionadmin']
         },
        canActivate: [RoleGuard]
      },
      {
         path:'viewallstudents',
         component:ViewallstudentsComponent,
         canActivate:[AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path:'**',redirectTo:'pageNotFound'
      },
      {
        path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'
      }


    ])
  ],
  providers: [ AuthGuard, UserService,AuthService,RoleGuard,JwtHelperService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }```




*here is my schema in mngodb*


```const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ClearAdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:
    {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true

    },
    admintype:{
        type:String,
        type:String,
        enum :['HOD','CICT','Sports','SUASAB','Admin']
    },
    university:{
        type:String,
        default:"Sokoine University of Agriculture"
    },
    college:{
       type:String,
       required:true
    },
    department:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

const ClearAdmin = mongoose.model('ClearAdmin', ClearAdminSchema);
module.exports = ClearAdmin;
````

The output doesn't navigate to either specific routes every thing works fine but navigation is the problem and I don't see any error on my code

Comment: the thing is target.queryselector won't work in angular 6, rather you need ngmodel to bind to variable in html. Another way is use HTMLInputElement which is built in module similar to queryselector

Comment: @phonemyatt no that one works fine i can even see what i subimtted on my console browser i think that shouldnt be the problem or what are u suggesting friend

Comment: if that's the case, what do you get in console when u receive the data? Maybe you need to check your if statement if(this.Auth.isAuthenticated(),data.token)

Comment: i get the the email and password which is the auth already but i cant navigate after that

Comment: you don't see any error because angular require to pipe with catcherror method from rxjs/operators. you can catch HttpErrorResponse like "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018259/angular-4-observable-catch-error". I suspect your getUserDetails body parameter is not correct. it suppose to be object

Comment: can you help me with that please brother @phonemyatt

Comment: In your authservice, add // private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {console.log(error);} and // getUserDetails(email: String,password:String){

    //post these details to the database
    return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/auth`,{ email,password}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  } and import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'; then tell me what is the error in console.

Comment: okay brother am on it

Comment: try this "return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/auth`,{ email: email, password: password});"

Comment: @phonemyatt i cant still navigate inspite of receiving the token

Comment: what's your router module look like? what's your route with auth guard and roles?

Comment: the files are all there brother the auth.gurad.role guard and the module too

Answer (score 0):

change this `this.router.navigate(['login']);` to `this.router.navigate(['/login']);`

- You can use dynamic navigate style like this.

  ```
       this.router.navigate(['/'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRouter});
  ```

  - in your connstructor out this.

    ```
     constructor (private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute)
    ```

Comment: where exactly should put that statement brother

Comment: the problem still persists brother

Comment: heloow could you help me please

Comment: may be you need canActivateChild() in auth.guard.ts because you are using AppRouter.forChild() in your app.module file.

Comment: And put this {path: '', redirectTo: 'login',  pathMatch: 'full'} to first and {path: '**', redirectTo: 'pageNotFound' } route to last in sequence.

Comment: still facing the problem cant navigate to specidific page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is wrong. but this part is to navigate to your route.

```
 this.Auth.getUserDetails(email,password).subscribe(data =>{
        if(this.Auth.isAuthenticated(data.token))
        {
         localStorage.setItem('token',data.token);
         this.router.navigate(['your-route']);
        }
      });
```

And roles are actually array. so in role guard

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    // this will be passed from the route config
    // on the data property
    const admintype = route.data.admintype;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // decode the token to get its payload
    const tokenPayload = decode(token);
    if (
      !this.auth.isAuthenticated() || 
      (tokenPayload.role && tokenPayload.role.indexof(admintype) === -1)  // This part may be giving some problem?
    ) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }    
    return true;
  }
```

you should check which of this getUserDetails or canActivate in role guard fire first. Because login flow should start in this way.

1. key in username and password
2. press login
3. fire login service and subscribe
4. login success, save auth token
5. route to desired page which trigger role guard

Comment: thanks brother but am still stuck dont know whats the problem exactly

Comment: cou;d we reach more [eople of my problem so that they can be of many help

Comment: @KyleMutta, if you can recreate exact same problem in stackblitz, more people can help you.